# Maven: vm args in MAVEN_OPTS arent working, but they are if specified in the command line

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin, vmargs

I have a particular test case that is run by surefire which fails when this vm arg is not set.

I am able to get the test to successfully pass if i run:

```
mvn test -Dtest=TestClass -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

This works great.  Now I want to generalize this so that the vm arg is set for all maven builds.

In my .bashrc I've added

```
MAVEN_OPTS='-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true'
```

I have confirmed via echoing the env variable that it is set.  This unfortunately does not make a difference for my test case.  What other considerations am I missing that would interfere here?

Thanks!
R

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#argLine) you can give a supplemental configuration to the maven-surefire-plugin:

```
<configuration>
  <argLine>-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true</argLine>
  ...
</configuration>
```